# Qt's odbc driver does not support LastInsertId with mysql, whats the workaround?

Tags: mysql, qt, odbc, last-insert-id

Im using Qt 4.8.3 and the MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver. The driver does not seem to support LastInsertId which I test like this:

```
db.driver()->hasFeature(QSqlDriver::LastInsertId)
```

I need it to find the auto increment id I just inserted

```
query.exec("INSERT INTO myTable (MyVal, Created) VALUES ('1', NOW())");
auto insertId = query.lastInsertId().toString();
```

What is the best workaround?

EDIT: there will be concurrent access to this table from multiple clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-functionality.html#connector-odbc-usagenotes-functionality-last-insert-id), you can call:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

after the insert query to get the latest id inserted for the current connection, even when using ODBC.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
query.exec("SELECT id FROM myTable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

to get the largest id in your table - this should be the one you just inserted.

If you are writing an application that can have multiple concurrent users you'll have to look into creating a lock on your table and then releasing the lock after you run this second query.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I will look into locking the table.

Answer (score 1):

Use OUTPUT INSERTED.[Field Name] as in code below.
Read the returned ID with next() function.

```
bool RepeatsRecognizer::InsertEvent(RepEvent* event){
QSqlDatabase db = AppManager::DB_Output()->ThreadDatabase();
QSqlQuery query(db);
query.prepare("INSERT INTO RepEvents (ChannelID, StatsRangeUID, MinStartDateTime, MaxDuration, Fixed) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID"
              " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
query.bindValue(0, event->ChannelID);
query.bindValue(1, event->StatsRangeUID.toString());
query.bindValue(2, event->MinStartDateTime);
query.bindValue(3, event->MaxDuration);
query.bindValue(4, false);


if (!query.exec())
    return false;

if (!query.next())
    return false;

event->ID = query.value(0).toLongLong();
qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << "Event ID:" << event->ID;
```

}