# QSqlTableModel doesn't retrieve last id from insert

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to retrieve the id of a record after an insert (Using PyQt5).
The database is MySql and the id is Not Null and auto-increment.
After executing the code below, the record is inserted correctly into the table, but the lastInsertId () command is returning None.

Can anyone tell me if there is anything wrong with the code? I appreciate the help.

```
from PyQt5 import QtSql

db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QMYSQL')
db.setHostName('localhost')
db.setUserName('root')
db.setPassword('')
db.setDatabaseName('teste')
db.open()

model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(None, db)
model.setTable("test_table")

record = QtSql.QSqlRecord(model.record())
record.setGenerated("id", True) # this line can be commented, the result is the same
record.setValue("column_test", "teste")
teste = model.insertRecord(-1, record)
print(model.query().lastInsertId()) #printed: None
print(model.lastError().text()) #printed: nothing
print(model.query().driver().hasFeature(QtSql.QSqlDriver.LastInsertId)) #printed: True
```

Comment: Does [this work-around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13715334/984421) give the correct value?

Comment: Thanks, creating a new query it works. I had to do something like this:  
  
'Query_last_id = QSqlQuery(db)
Query_last_id.exec ('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID ();')
Query_last_id.next ()
Print (query_last_id.value (0))'
  
@ekhumoro, do you think this is the best solution?

Comment: Well, it's a *working* solution ;-) I have no idea whether it is the "best", nor why `lastInsertId()` does not appear to work. Perhaps the problem is actually with `insertRecord()`. Maybe `lastInsertId()` will work if the insert is done "manually", using only a `QSqlQuery`.

Comment: While this post is quite old to answer but I think I know why it doesn't work. "insertRecord" creates a row, not an insertion in the DB. You must actually "commit" the insertion through "submit[All]" to make it effective and then using "lastInsertId" may return the effective ID you wanted.